# How to make script execution slow?

Tags: performance, node.js, cassandra, cpu-usage

I have the task: need to select data from "TABLE_FROM", modify it and insert to the "TABLE_TO". The main problem is script must run on production and shouldn't hurts live site performance, but "TABLE_FROM" contains hundred millions of rows. Going to run the script using nodejs. What techniques are using to resolve such kind of problems? ie. how to make this script running "slowly" or other words "softly" to prevent DB and CPU overload?

Time of script execution is irrelevant. I use Cassandra DB.

Comment: Can you set up a job queue and run the script within a setInterval() ?

Comment: I have the running job-server (nodejs KUE module). So you suggest to divide the job into small pieces and add them to the queue (with interval)? Also I thought about using setInterval for slow down the script, but not sure is it a good way?

Comment: setInterval() is not for slowing down, but for chunking the work into equally-distributed pieces. How much does one job cost, time-wise? If it is less than 20 miliseconds, then you could run it every 100ms or so. If you go down this road, don't use setInterval, but use setTimeout when the previous job finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
var OFFSET = 0;
var BATCHSIZE = 100;
var TIMEOUT = 1000;
function fetchPush() {
    // fetch from TABLE_FROM, possibly in batches
    rows = fetch(OFFSET, BATCHSIZE);

    // push to TABLE_TO
    push(rows);

    // do next batch in timeout
    setTimeout(fetchPush, TIMEOUT);
}
```

Here I'm assuming the fetch and push are blocking calls, for async processing you could (obviously) use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: How to set timeout when use async module for nodejs?

Comment: Ok, I found. Need to use async.series (next function runs on previous finished) and setTimeout for callback in each function. [Async series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)

Comment: Great. Actually you could use `async.waterfall()` to pass the output of first step (in your case the rows) as parameter of the next step. But that's logically identical to `async.series()` with variables in common scope.